# ImageMagick background image?

Tags: imagemagick

I just recently started to explore ImageMagick and I have a doubt. I have been searching but could not find a solution.

With the following code:

```
convert -background lightblue  -fill blue  -font Candice -pointsize 30 \
          -size 220x220  -gravity Center  caption:'$txt' \
          $name.gif
```

How do I use an image as background instead a static color?

I have tried `-background "file.jpg"` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`-texture`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#texture) instead of [`-background`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background).

Comment: I've tried to replace -background 'file.jpg' by -texture 'file.jpg' but it comes with white background

Answer (score 1):

I think I missunderstood your initial question. This will tile an image onto a set size background and add some text.

```
$txt = 'Caption';
// Tile the image - no background as it will not be seen behind the tile
$cmd = " -size 220x220 tile:noise.jpg -font Candice -fill blue -pointsize 30 ".
"-gravity Center -annotate +0+0 $txt";  
exec("convert $cmd output.jpg");
```

Comment: You have to specify full paths to fonts when using ImageMagick from the shell on OS X. `convert -size 220x220 tile:/Applications/Chess.app/Contents/Resources/selected_piece_texture.png -fill blue -font /Library/Fonts/Arial\ Narrow.ttf -pointsize 30 -gravity Center -annotate +0+0 "some text" output.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few ways depending the effect you are after but this is one simple way:

convert input.jpg  -fill blue  -font Candice -pointsize 30 -gravity Center -annotate +0+0 "Some text" $name.gif

I can not get the hang of the way this site posts code :(